# Module similar to module filter to filter content and users?

Tags: 7

I use [Module filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter) module to filter the long list of modules. It comes very handy to find a module rather than using CTRL+F always. I was wondering if there is a module which can filter the content (at admin/content) and/or users (at admin/people) as well.

Comment: This is the one I am using and find it good enough http://drupal.org/project/cmf/

Comment: @kantu it only has version for D6.. I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contentment](http://drupal.org/project/contentment) (along with [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)) looks like a winning combination.